capture all values for a list
I need some help to get all values from a attribute (in a body field) and transform in a list at freemarker to compare each value with possible values in another list.
Below you have the example of attribute I should capture the values.
"customField1067": [
    {
        "id": "e7e5b4cb-8275-48ca-9a0f-3e01dd0c2dd8",
        "value": "10120000",
        "valueKey": "e7e5b4cb-8275-48ca-9a0f-3e01dd0c2dd8"
    },
    {
        "id": "f12fa695-d456-4645-9d1b-f7c3909cf776",
        "value": "10100000",
        "valueKey": "f12fa695-d456-4645-9d1b-f7c3909cf776"
    },
    {
        "id": "4ce062f9-541d-4e8b-b5ee-b4bc73fd415f",
        "value": "10110000",
        "valueKey": "4ce062f9-541d-4e8b-b5ee-b4bc73fd415f"
    }
],

I tried to use the code bellow, but I got sintaxe errors
<#assign taskKeys = [(step.http_0.customField1064.value)]>
    <#list taskKeys as key>
        ${key} 
    </#list>


this one works with your data
<#assign tasks = customField1067>
<#list tasks as task>
    ${task.value} 
</#list>

output is
    10120000 
    10100000 
    10110000 

What I noticed, there is a typo '1067' in a model and '1064' in a code. And based on your model customField1064 is an array, and array doesn't have the value field. So I'm not sure why you expect the following to work (step.http_0.customField1064.value)
